# Images used in training CNN model

Tags: pytorch, image

I am training a CNN with RGB images, however, when i plot them, they display in a bluish color. How can I have these display in RGB. Also do you think this affects the model accuracy?[image]

The code i am using to display is below: index_to_display = 5  # Replace this with the desired index

## Iterate over the DataLoader until you reach the desired index

for idx, batch in enumerate(train_loader):
if idx == index_to_display:
images, labels = batch

```
    # Access the specific image and label
    image_to_display = images[0]  # Assuming you want to display the first image in the batch
    label_to_display = labels[0].item()

    # Convert the image tensor to a NumPy array for visualization
    image_array = image_to_display.permute(1, 2, 0).numpy()
    image_array = (image_array * 255).astype('uint8')

    # Convert the NumPy array to PIL Image
    pil_image = transforms.ToPILImage()(image_array)  # Convert to uint8
    img2 = F.adjust_hue(pil_image, 0) # returns original image

    # Display the image
    plt.imshow(img2)
    plt.title(f"Image at index {index_to_display} with label {label_to_display}")
    plt.show()

    break  # Break out of the loop once the desired index is rea
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your RGB order got mixed up. Likely from `image_array = image_to_display.permute(1, 2, 0).numpy()`.